# Unhandled exception throwing with a clean UWP project

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

Before starting I would like to point out that I have no knowledge at all developing windows apps.

I'm following [this microsoft tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-xaml-universal) to create a very easy Hello World app to begin learning but when I compile and run it out of the box (Open VS2015 Community Edition, create new C# Universal Windows Blank app, run local machine) I'm getting a lot of erros. I've been researching on Stack Overflow and googling but I can't manage to find solutions.

I would be really grateful if someone explained me what to do in order to compile and run the app, maybe I'm missing enviroment configuration variables or... I don't really know.

Thank you in advance.

Here are the scrreenshots of the errors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you check if .NET Framwork is enabled in Windows feature (Control Panel) ?

Comment: Yes, :NET Framework is enabled

Comment: I think the problem is related to your Windows installed. My best advise is reinstall Windows.